# #if net48 results in compiler error because components are missing

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I'm working to migrate an application to .netcore and want to keep one of the local libraries available for .Net Framework 4.8. However it uses components from System.Web.Security so I used [compiler directives](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/target-multiple-frameworks-in-aspnet-core2) to leave those components out for target framework versions other than the latest framework. In .net core I will not be needing these features anyway. However the compiler treats my code within the directives as non-existent, as shown in the following example:

```
// A project with <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
namespace Framework {
  public class A {
    public B Test; // Error, B is unknown.
  } // Class A
#if net48
  public class B {

  }
#endif 

} // Namespace Framework
```

A project with the following SDK-style csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
      <TargetFrameworks>net48</TargetFrameworks>
      <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

So I'm not even targetting netstandard2.0 yet and just within net48 there's a problem. If you think providing a single target framework requires the XML element to be singular, I've also tried that, it makes no difference.

Comment: Did you try `#if NET48` instead of `#if net48`?

Comment: @JeffE Thanks, that's it, if you change to the answer I'll accept it. I was confused by the value passed on in the csproj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The framework properties need to be capitalized: `#if NET48`